# Como tornar o cmd mais lento

Tags: c, c++, debug, cmd

Existe algum comando para que o `cmd` execute um programa que eu mande rodar a partir do compilador? Gostaria de Debugar o que fiz e, como frequentemente caio em loop infinito, quero saber se tem como fazer o `cmd` executar de forma mais lenta (muito mais lenta) para que de tempo de ver em que ponto o programa está travando.

Comment: Já experimentou utilizar uma `IDE` para debuggar de verdade?

Comment: Com que ferramentas é que escreves e compilas os programas? Para além dos IDEs também há "debuggers" à parte como o `gdb`. Normalmente, podes usar "breakpoints" para fazer o "debugger" parar numa linha do código, e depois avançar passo a passo.

Answer (score 2):

A tua melhor opcao 'e usar um *debugger*.
Com um debugger podes correr o programa linha a linha, podes inspeccionar o valor de variaveis antes e depois de cada instrucao ou funcao, podes mudar o valor de variaveis dinamicamente, ..., ...

Cada compilador tem o seu debugger especifico. Muitos IDEs integram o debugger no ambiente de desenvolvimento de forma natural; se ao usas IDE o uso do debugger pode nao ser tao natural mas 'e perfeitamente razoavel.

Outra forma que tens 'e usar `printf`s dentro do programa para veres o que esta a acontecer a uma ou mais variaveis

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    fprintf(stderr, "DEBUGGING: i = %d; j = %d; x = %f\n", i, j, x);
    /* resto do loop */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar interruptores (Exemplo abaixo... Não funciona em todos os locais, pois a instrução pode variar entre plataformas) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

   const int teste = 3;
   __asm__ ("int3");
   int teste2 = 5;
   __asm__("int3");

  return 0;
}
```

gcc -g teste.c

gdb a.out

run

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
main () at teste.c:8
8      int teste2 = 5;
```

continue

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
main () at teste.c:13
13    return 0;
```

Para ver o conteúdo das variáveis, só digitar: info locals

```
(gdb) info locals
teste = 3
teste2 = 5
```